PJSIP - outgoing video call does not transmit video
I'm using Orange Pi Zero 3 with Ubuntu 22.04.4. It is important for me to make a video call with Orange Pi. There is no need to accept the video, because Orange Pi has no screen. The initiator of the communication is always the Orange Pi.
I installed pjproject-2.14.1 following the instructions. I'm using the standard pjsua application. I launch it with my configuration. I execute the video enable command vid enable, then make a call to my Android phone with SIP. An incoming call appears on the phone and three buttons are shown: reject call, reply with video, reply with audio. I click the reply with video button. A dark screen appears where there should be a video from Orange Pi and a small window where I see myself from the phone camera. As I understand it, the video call goes through, but for some reason the video from the Orange Pi camera does not go through. In Orange Pi I use a USB camera. Installed v4l-utils to use the camera. I tested the camera and it works well. Running ./aconfigure I made sure that v4l2 is supported - checking for v4l2_open in -lv4l2... yes. Installed the H264 codec. In the config_site.h file I specified
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO       1
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_OPENH264_CODEC      1

How do I configure pjsua so that I can make a video call from Orange Pi?
I launch pjsua with the command ./pjsua-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --config-file sip.conf. Configuration file sip.conf:
--id sip:1003@172.16.35.30
--registrar sip:172.16.35.30
--realm *
--username 1003
--password PASSWORD

When running pjsua and executing the vid commands I can see the following:
>>> vid dev list
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c !Video device list:
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c  3 device(s) detected:
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c   -1 USB 2.0 Camera: USB 2.0 Camera [v4l2][capture] (default capture device)
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported capabilities: format
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported formats: YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c    0 USB 2.0 Camera: USB 2.0 Camera [v4l2][capture]
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported capabilities: format
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported formats: YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, YUY2, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, RGB24, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420, I420
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c    1 Colorbar generator [Colorbar][capture]
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported capabilities: format
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported formats: YUY2, UYVY, YVYU, RGBA, RGB24, BGRA, YV12, I420, I422, I420JPG, I422JPG
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c    2 Colorbar-active [Colorbar][capture]
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported capabilities: format
10:45:31.512     pjsua_app_common.c      Supported formats: YUY2, UYVY, YVYU, RGBA, RGB24, BGRA, YV12, I420, I422, I420JPG, I422JPG

>>> vid codec list
10:46:18.840     pjsua_app_legacy.c !Found 1 video codecs:
10:46:18.840     pjsua_app_legacy.c  codec id      prio  fps    bw(kbps)   size
10:46:18.840     pjsua_app_legacy.c  ------------------------------------------
10:46:18.840     pjsua_app_legacy.c  H264/97       128   15.00   256/ 256  720x480

pjsua launch log:
       sip_endpoint.c !.Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
           alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA driver found 28 devices
           alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA initialized
                pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0xaaaaf7c612a8)
          pjsua_vid.c  ..Initializing video subsystem..
           vid_conf.c  ...Created video conference bridge with 32 ports
         openh264.cpp  ...OpenH264 codec initialized
           v4l2_dev.c  ...Video4Linux2 has 1 devices
            sdl_dev.c !SDL_Init() error: No available video device
       colorbar_dev.c !...Colorbar video src initialized with 2 device(s):
       colorbar_dev.c  ... 0: Colorbar generator
       colorbar_dev.c  ... 1: Colorbar-active
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
       sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
         pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
         pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.14.1 for Linux-6.1.31/aarch64/glibc-2.35 initialized
         pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
       sip_endpoint.c  Module "mod-default-handler" registered
         pjsua_core.c  SIP UDP socket reachable at 192.168.88.248:5060
    udp0xaaaaf7c24490  SIP UDP transport started, published address is 192.168.88.248:5060
          pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=<sip:192.168.88.248:5060>
          pjsua_acc.c  .Account <sip:192.168.88.248:5060> added with id 0
          pjsua_acc.c  Modifying account 0
          pjsua_acc.c  Acc 0: setting online status to 1..
           tcptp:5060  SIP TCP listener ready for incoming connections at 192.168.88.248:5060
          pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=<sip:192.168.88.248:5060;transport=TCP>
          pjsua_acc.c  .Account <sip:192.168.88.248:5060;transport=TCP> added with id 1
          pjsua_acc.c  Modifying account 1
          pjsua_acc.c  Acc 1: setting online status to 1..
          pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:1003@172.16.35.30
          pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:1003@172.16.35.30 added with id 2
          pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 2: setting registration..
         pjsua_core.c  ...TX 545 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=30933 (tdta0xaaaaf7d42538) to UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
REGISTER sip:172.16.35.30 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjO-GKItJy3svN4YQkj3IvNCe1jt64kP9Q
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>;tag=UXUlxGCOLXbiAi.4w7HWZP.on46-OQPQ
To: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>
Call-ID: .W8Xzpy1TZbmyIPfzQmQRw5eucP4SxVe
CSeq: 30933 REGISTER
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.14.1 Linux-6.1.31/aarch64/glibc-2.35
Contact: <sip:1003@192.168.88.248:5060;ob>
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
       pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 2: Registration sent
       pjsua_acc.c  Acc 2: setting online status to 1..
      pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
    sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
      pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
            main.c  Ready: Success
>>>>
Account list:
  [ 0] <sip:192.168.88.248:5060>: does not register
       Online status: Online
  [ 1] <sip:192.168.88.248:5060;transport=TCP>: does not register
       Online status: Online
 *[ 2] sip:1003@172.16.35.30: 100/In Progress (expires=0)
       Online status: Online
Buddy list:
 -none-

+=============================================================================+
|       Call Commands:         |   Buddy, IM & Presence:  |     Account:      |
|                              |                          |                   |
|  m  Make new call            | +b  Add new buddy        | +a  Add new accnt.|
|  M  Make multiple calls      | -b  Delete buddy         | -a  Delete accnt. |
|  a  Answer call              |  i  Send IM              | !a  Modify accnt. |
|  h  Hangup call  (ha=all)    |  s  Subscribe presence   | rr  (Re-)register |
|  H  Hold call                |  u  Unsubscribe presence | ru  Unregister    |
|  v  re-inVite (release hold) |  t  Toggle online status |  >  Cycle next ac.|
|  U  send UPDATE              |  T  Set online status    |  <  Cycle prev ac.|
| ],[ Select next/prev call    +--------------------------+-------------------+
|  x  Xfer call                |      Media Commands:     |  Status & Config: |
|  X  Xfer with Replaces       |                          |                   |
|  #  Send RFC 2833 DTMF       | cl  List ports           |  d  Dump status   |
|  *  Send DTMF with INFO      | cc  Connect port         | dd  Dump detailed |
| dq  Dump curr. call quality  | cd  Disconnect port      | dc  Dump config   |
|                              |  V  Adjust audio Volume  |  f  Save config   |
|  S  Send arbitrary REQUEST   | Cp  Codec priorities     |                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Video: "vid help" for more info                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  q  QUIT      L  ReLoad       I  IP change     n  detect NAT type           |
|  sleep MS     echo [0|1|txt]                                                |
+=============================================================================+
You have 0 active call

...

vid enable
11:33:28.300     pjsua_app_legacy.c !Video will be enabled in next offer/answer
>>> m
(You currently have 0 calls)
Buddy list:
 -none-

Choices:
   0         For current dialog.
  URL        An URL
  <Enter>    Empty input (or 'q') to cancel
Make call: sip:1001@172.16.35.30
          pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #2 to sip:1001@172.16.35.30
           pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2, mode=0, use_default_settings=0
           pjsua_app.c  ..Turning sound device -1 -2 ON
           pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
      ec0xaaaaf7d49ea0  ...Speex AEC created, clock_rate=16000, channel=1, samples per frame=320, tail length=200 ms, latency=0 ms
         pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
         pjsua_media.c !..RTP socket reachable at 192.168.88.248:4000
         pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 192.168.88.248:4001
    srtp0xaaaaf7d7ca80  ..SRTP transport created
         pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 192.168.88.248:4002
         pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 192.168.88.248:4003
    srtp0xaaaaf7d81660  ..SRTP transport created
         pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
     udp0xaaaaf7d401d0  ..UDP media transport created
     udp0xaaaaf7d79640  ..UDP media transport created
    tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8  ....TCP client transport created
    tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8  ....TCP transport 192.168.88.248:41061 is connecting to 172.16.35.30:5060...
          pjsua_core.c  ....TX 1543 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=5956 (tdta0xaaaaf7d88538) to TCP 172.16.35.30:5060:
INVITE sip:1001@172.16.35.30 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.88.248:41061;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjjL4lBgtK.4r81hOxylLB5paA3-df6Fjo;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:1003@172.16.35.30;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: sip:1001@172.16.35.30
Contact: <sip:1003@192.168.88.248:5060;ob>
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
CSeq: 5956 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.14.1 Linux-6.1.31/aarch64/glibc-2.35
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   892

...

--end msg--
    pjsua_app.c  .......Call 0 state changed to CALLING
>>> 11:33:40.468     tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8 !TCP connect() error: [code=120111]: Connection refused
    tsx0xaaaaf7d8b4a8  Temporary failure in sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5956 (tdta0xaaaaf7d88538), will try next server: Connection refused
         pjsua_core.c  TX 1536 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=5956 (tdta0xaaaaf7d88538) to UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
INVITE sip:1001@172.16.35.30 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjjL4lBgtK.4r81hOxylLB5paA3-df6Fjo
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:1003@172.16.35.30;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: sip:1001@172.16.35.30
Contact: <sip:1003@192.168.88.248:5060;ob>
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
CSeq: 5956 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.14.1 Linux-6.1.31/aarch64/glibc-2.35
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   892

v=0
o=- 3928379620 3928379620 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
s=pjmedia
b=AS:352
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 96 97 98 99 3 0 8 9 120 121 122
c=IN IP4 192.168.88.248
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:98 speex/32000
a=rtpmap:99 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:99 mode=30
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:120 telephone-event/16000
a=fmtp:120 0-16
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=rtpmap:122 telephone-event/32000
a=fmtp:122 0-16
a=ssrc:1077023312 cname:3b3d295b63c2ac11
m=video 4002 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 192.168.88.248
b=TIAS:256000
a=rtcp:4003 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1
a=ssrc:804141558 cname:3b3d295b63c2ac11
a=rtcp-fb:* nack pli

--end msg--
           pjsua_app.c  SIP TCP transport is disconnected from 172.16.35.30:5060: Connection refused [status=120111]
           pjsua_acc.c  Disconnected notification for transport tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8
       sip_transport.c  .Transport tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8 shutting down, force=0
       sip_transport.c  Transport tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8 is being destroyed due to timeout in idle timer
    tcpc0xaaaaf7d8e1b8  TCP transport destroyed with reason 120111: Connection refused
          pjsua_core.c  .RX 568 bytes Response msg 401/INVITE/cseq=5956 (rdata0xffffa8006288) from UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.88.248;branch=z9hG4bKPjjL4lBgtK.4r81hOxylLB5paA3-df6Fjo
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
From: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: <sip:1001@172.16.35.30>;tag=z9hG4bKPjjL4lBgtK.4r81hOxylLB5paA3-df6Fjo
CSeq: 5956 INVITE
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="grandstream",nonce="1719390820/66d852ad932ebfcee84c131fd5afe9e1",opaque="6553a6c932a384e2",algorithm=md5,qop="auth"
Server: Grandstream UCM6202V1.4A 1.0.17.16
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
    pjsua_core.c  ..TX 366 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=5956 (tdta0xffffa800b1b8) to UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
ACK sip:1001@172.16.35.30 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjjL4lBgtK.4r81hOxylLB5paA3-df6Fjo
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:1003@172.16.35.30;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: sip:1001@172.16.35.30;tag=z9hG4bKPjjL4lBgtK.4r81hOxylLB5paA3-df6Fjo
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
CSeq: 5956 ACK
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
    sip_auth_client.c  ....Digest algorithm is "md5"
         pjsua_core.c  .......TX 1831 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=5957 (tdta0xaaaaf7d88538) to UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
INVITE sip:1001@172.16.35.30 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjuG43Waa8WtEwIFz4qW8V3dHylr7KLjyJ
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:1003@172.16.35.30;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: sip:1001@172.16.35.30
Contact: <sip:1003@192.168.88.248:5060;ob>
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
CSeq: 5957 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.14.1 Linux-6.1.31/aarch64/glibc-2.35
Authorization: Digest username="1003", realm="grandstream", nonce="1719390820/66d852ad932ebfcee84c131fd5afe9e1", uri="sip:1001@172.16.35.30", response="e4de83681be2ae57ca0d51ffc8c0b318", algorithm=md5, cnonce="yvM.vjLpWTJcgkly58MblUDmGjawuQE2", opaque="6553a6c932a384e2", qop=auth, nc=00000001
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   892

v=0
o=- 3928379620 3928379620 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
s=pjmedia
b=AS:352
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 96 97 98 99 3 0 8 9 120 121 122
c=IN IP4 192.168.88.248
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:98 speex/32000
a=rtpmap:99 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:99 mode=30
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:120 telephone-event/16000
a=fmtp:120 0-16
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=rtpmap:122 telephone-event/32000
a=fmtp:122 0-16
a=ssrc:1077023312 cname:3b3d295b63c2ac11
m=video 4002 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 192.168.88.248
b=TIAS:256000
a=rtcp:4003 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1
a=ssrc:804141558 cname:3b3d295b63c2ac11
a=rtcp-fb:* nack pli

--end msg--
    pjsua_core.c  .RX 367 bytes Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=5957 (rdata0xffffa8006288) from UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.88.248;branch=z9hG4bKPjuG43Waa8WtEwIFz4qW8V3dHylr7KLjyJ
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
From: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: <sip:1001@172.16.35.30>
CSeq: 5957 INVITE
Server: Grandstream UCM6202V1.4A 1.0.17.16
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
    pjsua_core.c  .RX 565 bytes Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=5957 (rdata0xffffa8006288) from UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.88.248;branch=z9hG4bKPjuG43Waa8WtEwIFz4qW8V3dHylr7KLjyJ
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
From: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: <sip:1001@172.16.35.30>;tag=45f67688-c786-472c-8038-391535bdc5c1
CSeq: 5957 INVITE
Server: Grandstream UCM6202V1.4A 1.0.17.16
Contact: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30:5060>
Allow: OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REFER, MESSAGE, REGISTER
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
     pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 1 --> 0
    conference.c  ......Port 1 (ringback) transmitting to port 0 (default)
     pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 state changed to EARLY (180 Ringing)
    pjsua_core.c  .RX 1196 bytes Response msg 200/INVITE/cseq=5957 (rdata0xffffa8006288) from UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.88.248;branch=z9hG4bKPjuG43Waa8WtEwIFz4qW8V3dHylr7KLjyJ
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
From: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: <sip:1001@172.16.35.30>;tag=45f67688-c786-472c-8038-391535bdc5c1
CSeq: 5957 INVITE
Server: Grandstream UCM6202V1.4A 1.0.17.16
Allow: OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REFER, MESSAGE, REGISTER
Contact: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30:5060>
Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac
Require: timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   501

v=0
o=- 3928379620 3928379622 IN IP4 172.16.35.30
s=Asterisk
c=IN IP4 172.16.35.30
b=CT:384
t=0 0
m=audio 11522 RTP/AVP 0 8 99 3 9 121
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:99 iLBC/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=maxptime:30
a=sendrecv
m=video 13128 RTP/AVP 97
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01e;session-id=6
a=ssrc-group:FID 653703365 1878771249
a=sendrecv

--end msg--
             pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 state changed to CONNECTING
       inv0xaaaaf7d782b8  ....SDP negotiation done: Success
           pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: updating media..
           pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
       udp0xaaaaf7d401d0  ......UDP media transport started
             pjsua_aud.c  ......Audio channel update..
      strm0xffffa8012b98  .......VAD temporarily disabled
       udp0xaaaaf7d401d0  .......UDP media transport attached
      strm0xffffa8012b98  .......Encoder stream started
      strm0xffffa8012b98  .......Decoder stream started
           pjsua_media.c  ......Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
           pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
       udp0xaaaaf7d79640  ......UDP media transport started
             pjsua_vid.c  ......Video channel update..
       udp0xaaaaf7d79640  .......UDP media transport attached
    vstenc0xffffa80191f8  .......Encoder stream started
    vstdec0xffffa80191f8  .......Decoder stream started
             pjsua_vid.c  .......Setting up RX..
             pjsua_vid.c  ........Creating video window: type=stream, cap_id=-1, rend_id=-2
             pjsua_vid.c  .........Window 0: destroying..
           pjsua_media.c  ......pjsua_vid_channel_update() failed for call_id 0 media 1: Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)
             pjsua_vid.c  .......Stopping video stream..
            vid_stream.c  ........Destroy request on vstrm0xffffa80191f8..
       udp0xaaaaf7d79640  ........UDP media transport detached
            vid_stream.c  ........Destroying vstrm0xffffa80191f8..
           pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
      srtp0xaaaaf7d81660  ......Destroying SRTP transport
       udp0xaaaaf7d79640  ......UDP media transport destroyed
      srtp0xaaaaf7d81660  ......SRTP transport destroyed
           pjsua_media.c  ......Error updating media call00:1: Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)
             pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 media 0 [type=audio], status is Active
             pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf disconnect: 1 -x- 0
            conference.c  ......Port 1 (ringback) stop transmitting to port 0 (default)
             pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 3 --> 0
            conference.c  ......Port 3 (sip:1001@172.16.35.30) transmitting to port 0 (default)
             pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 0 --> 3
            conference.c  ......Port 0 (default) transmitting to port 3 (sip:1001@172.16.35.30)
             pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 media 1 [type=video], status is Error
            pjsua_core.c  .....TX 366 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=5957 (tdta0xffffa80a01b8) to UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
ACK sip:1003@172.16.35.30:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjvXPbSMAwXWQQsiAHvbg1zwz0vSp.S1X0
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:1003@172.16.35.30;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: sip:1001@172.16.35.30;tag=45f67688-c786-472c-8038-391535bdc5c1
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
CSeq: 5957 ACK
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
     pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 state changed to CONFIRMED
    pjsua_call.c  .Call 0 sending UPDATE for updating media session to use only one codec
    pjsua_core.c  ....TX 917 bytes Request msg UPDATE/cseq=5958 (tdta0xffffa80a3118) to UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
UPDATE sip:1003@172.16.35.30:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjTeJPQL6c5KiYwI1VAfGtjYNuP6FW-rjU
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:1003@172.16.35.30;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: sip:1001@172.16.35.30;tag=45f67688-c786-472c-8038-391535bdc5c1
Contact: <sip:1003@192.168.88.248:5060;ob>
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
CSeq: 5958 UPDATE
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac
Min-SE: 90
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   370

v=0
o=- 3928379620 3928379621 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 0 121
c=IN IP4 192.168.88.248
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 192.168.88.248
a=ssrc:1077023312 cname:3b3d295b63c2ac11
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=sendrecv
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 31
c=IN IP6 ::1
a=inactive

--end msg--
          Master/sound !Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
    strm0xffffa8012b98  Resetting jitter buffer in stream playback start
          pjsua_core.c  .RX 1023 bytes Response msg 200/UPDATE/cseq=5958 (rdata0xffffa8006288) from UDP 172.16.35.30:5060:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.88.248:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.88.248;branch=z9hG4bKPjTeJPQL6c5KiYwI1VAfGtjYNuP6FW-rjU
Call-ID: WNTOADIZ1qrB8WMp1A9RYoboZcIoKTl8
From: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30>;tag=1ZPzRmSVenuLls.D550vPZW1uR-rbK54
To: <sip:1001@172.16.35.30>;tag=45f67688-c786-472c-8038-391535bdc5c1
CSeq: 5958 UPDATE
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac
Require: timer
Contact: <sip:1003@172.16.35.30:5060>
Allow: OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REFER, MESSAGE, REGISTER
Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub
Server: Grandstream UCM6202V1.4A 1.0.17.16
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   328

v=0
o=- 3928379620 3928379623 IN IP4 172.16.35.30
s=Asterisk
c=IN IP4 172.16.35.30
t=0 0
m=audio 11522 RTP/AVP 0 121
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=rtcp:11523 IN IP4 172.16.35.30
a=sendrecv
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 31
c=IN IP4 172.16.35.30
a=inactive

--end msg--
     inv0xaaaaf7d782b8  ....SDP negotiation done: Success
         pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: updating media..
     udp0xaaaaf7d401d0  .......UDP media transport detached
         pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
     udp0xaaaaf7d401d0  ......UDP media transport started
           pjsua_aud.c  ......Audio channel update..
    strm0xffffa8011b88  .......VAD temporarily disabled
     udp0xaaaaf7d401d0  .......UDP media transport attached
    strm0xffffa8011b88  .......Encoder stream started
    strm0xffffa8011b88  .......Decoder stream started
         pjsua_media.c  ......Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
         pjsua_media.c  ......pjmedia_vid_stream_info_from_sdp() failed for call_id 0 media 1: Unsupported address family (PJ_EAFNOTSUP)
         pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
         pjsua_media.c  ......Error updating media call00:1: Unsupported address family (PJ_EAFNOTSUP)
           pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 media 0 [type=audio], status is Active
           pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 3 --> 0
          conference.c  ......Port 3 (sip:1001@172.16.35.30) transmitting to port 0 (default)
           pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 0 --> 3
          conference.c  ......Port 0 (default) transmitting to port 3 (sip:1001@172.16.35.30)
           pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 media 1 [type=video], status is Error
    strm0xffffa8011b88 !Resetting jitter buffer in stream playback start
    strm0xffffa8011b88  VAD re-enabled

